# Ошибка - необъявленный идентификатор

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Когда программирую на `C++` в `Visual Studio`, появляется ошибка в операторах `сout` и `cin`. Компилятор пишет, что эти операторы не объявлены (undeclared identifier). Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

**Добавлено.**

Все равно ничего не получается

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    //объявление переменной:
    double V,T,alpha;
    //грави постоянная:
    const double g=9.8;
    //Ввод параметров:
    cout<<"V = ";-здесь выводит ошибку
    cin>>V;-и здесь
    cout<<"T = ";
    cin >>T;
    alpha = asin(g*T/2*V);
    cout<<"Значение угла альфа равно = "<<alpha;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Версия среды (компилятора) какая?

Comment: Либо я не знаю, как решить вашу проблему, либо вопрос надо переформулировать.

Comment: В коде вроде все путем, может быть криво создан проект в самой IDE?

Answer (score 4):

Поменяй местами `#include <iostream>` и `#include "stdafx.h"` (`"stdafx.h"` должно стоять первым).

Answer (score 2):

Для правильной работы вам надо:

1. Подключить библиотеку `iostream`.
2. Воспользоваться конструкцией `using namespace std` для разрешения области видимости.

Пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello std!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, надо было приводить версию среды, т.к. в Студии 2010 работает вполне нормально. В более старых версиях надо читать внимательно сообщения построения. Так, там наверняка должно быть сообщение типа "iostream: файл пропущен при поиске файла предкомпилированных заголовков", а именно -- "stdafx.h". Поставьте `#include "stdafx.h"` в **САМОМ НАЧАЛЕ**, и да будет Вам счастье.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Требуется создать в VS пустой проект  
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <cmath>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
setlocale(0,"russian");
//объявление переменной:
double V,T,alpha;
//грави постоянная:
const double g=9.8;
//Ввод параметров:
cout << "V="; //-здесь выводит ошибку
cin >> V; //-и здесь
cout << "T=";
cin >> T;
alpha = asin(g*T/2*V);
cout << "Значение угла альфа равно = "<<alpha;
_getch();
 }
```

Но лучше все это дело через std::cin и std::cout

Comment: Не путайте C и C++.

Comment: Исправленый вариант больше нравится?